# Have trouble with passing data from a function to a statefulwidget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have trouble with passing a big list of data from the function "Categories"

```
 Categories(productInfos),
```

to the statefulwidget in flutter. See picture how I have tried to insert the productInfos. You can also see in the picture that the value I get is null and not the data list.

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code and be more clear regarding your problem?

Comment: Why are you adding a 2nd "productInfos" in the Categories constructor? Might want to try removing the first one - cause you don't seem to be using its value? The way I see it, you're setting productInfos and passing productInfoss to the state (which will always be null that way)

Answer (score 1):

Might want to try something like this (note you can access your widget's ProductInfo in the state via widget.productInfo):

```
class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductInfo productInfo;

  Categories({this.productInfo, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategoriesState createState() => _CategoriesState();
}

class _CategoriesState extends State<Categories> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pi = widget.productInfo;
    return Container();
  }
}
```